# How Do I Intercept Banner in WordPress?

Tags: header, wordpress, banner, intercept

My client wants me to make a plugin that intercepts the banner on a WordPress blog so that the existing one displays, but right beneath it, above the content and the sidebar, another banner appears. And he needs it such that it works in most themes and isn't theme-specific.

I found I could use add_action('loop_start','interceptMe') to put something at the top before posts or a single post, but it still left the sidebar on the right. I have tried using add_action('all','test') to dump out different intercepts to see if I could figure this out, but I just can't seem to get it yet. I'm thinking I may have to intercept all esc_html calls and contextually inspect that until I find one used for the banner.

Does anyone know how to intercept the banner to add another one right beneath it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be very challenging to do. There's no consistent structure, HTML, or CSS IDs that would allow you to do cross-theme injection like this (hell, some themes don't *have* a header image). You will likely need to make manual changes to each theme for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might insert some JavaScript that looks for an H1 tag and inserts your banner right after it.  Ceejayoz is right though -- there's not consistency to different themes.  One theme might use H1 for the site header and another for a Post title.